# how to suppress cpio warning: file on disk is not older; skipping

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-mountain-lion

I create shadow copies of big directories using cpio (`find . | cpio -pdm destination`)

After upgrade to Mountain Lion, cpio now warns me about every file that it didn't copy, i.e. `cpio: ./some-file: File on disk is not older; skipping.`

I could redirect `stderr`; however, I do want to know about real errors like destination full.

`cpio --quiet` does not help.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It means files on your destination are more recent than your source.
This may come from a wrong current time on your machine.
If you are sure you want to overwrite, you can use `-u` cpio switch:
from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cpio.1.html :

```
-u  (i and p modes) Unconditionally overwrite existing files.  Ordinarily, an older file will not overwrite a newer file on disk.
```

Comment: Copying only the newer files is the whole point of using cpio. On Leopard cpio silently ignores the unchanged files but on Mountain Lion it warns me for every one of them. I would like the Leopard behavior again.